# selenium Expected conditon selector By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT not working

Tags: css, facebook, selenium

I want to store friend list of a facebook id. For that whenever I click the Friends tab on profile , friend list is opened if friend list is not blocked otherwise other things open.

so to check if the friend list is opened or blocked , i select the element which is present if friend list is opened as follows:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 4).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT,"friends_all")))
except:
    print " friend list is blocked"
    browser.close()
```

and HTML Of element is as follows:

```
<a class="_3c_ _3s-" href="https://www.facebook.com/tripti.vishnoiji/friends_all" aria-controls="pagelet_timeline_app_collection_100001042287600:2356318349:2" role="tab" aria-selected="true" name="All friends" id="u_jsonp_2_0">
 <span class="_3sz">All friends</span>
 <span class="_3d0"></span>
 <div class="_3s_"></div>
</a>
```

The output showing is:
friend list is blocked

why element is not selected.

Comment: Did you tried using `WebDriverWait(browser, 4).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME,"All friends")))`

Comment: Try this code `WebDriverWait(browser, 4).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT,"All friends")))`.

Comment: @Harish thank u very much it is working

Comment: You can accept the answer if it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
    WebDriverWait(browser, 4).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT,"All friends")))
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to refer to `href` attribute of `a`, while actual link text is `"All friends"` and it's not contains `"friends_all"`

Try to use following code:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 4).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//a[span[text()="All friends"]]')))
```

or

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 4).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT,'All friends')))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Link Text**

This is a simple method of locating a hyperlink in your web page by using the text of the link.

e.g.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Launch Google</a>
```

Here `Link Text` would be `Launch Google`.

**Partial Link Text:**

As the name suggests `Partial Link Text` is just the partial word combination of the entire `Link Text` e.g. `Launch`, `Google` & `Launch Google`

So Partial link text in the above example would be either `All`, `Friends` & `All Friends`

In the above HTML, href contains `friends_all`, it is not the partial link text.

so if you want to click on the link you can use following:-

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 4).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//span[text()='All friends'])))
```